# how does switch_root command make /sbin/init in the new filesystem pid 1 process?

Tags: linux, root, systemd, initramfs

when kernel boots into initramfs, an init process is started and do some preparations for the real rootfs. when the real rootfs is ready, the init process in the initramfs should hand over to another init from the real rootfs.

my question is:
when init(old) already has process id 1, how come the new init process also has process id 1?

someone says the handover is done using switch_root command, I read the code and found out that switch_root only mounts /dev, proc etc., change root to new fs and then execv(/sbin/init).

switch_root should be executed as a child process of init(old) and should have a process id of 2,3 or anything but 1. right?

Comment: Why should `execv` not keep the PID 1?

Comment: @user17732522 I means switch_root command is ran in a shell, which is a subprocess of systemd, and thus the process execv'ing switch_root does not have pid 1.